# Having an issue converting an object to a filtered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, filter

I'd like to filter and restructure some specific data, but I'm having some trouble getting it to produce the proper structure.

I have this data response in this structure....

```
var response = {
   badProperty1: "bad property text"
   goodProperty1: "abc"
   goodProperty2: "bcd"
   goodProperty3: "cde"
   goodProperty4: "def"
   goodProperty5: "efg"
   badProperty2: "fgh"
};
```

I'd like to convert my response object into an array like this structure exactly...

```
var newFilteredStructuredArray = [
   {goodProperty1: 'abc'},
   {goodProperty2: 'bcd'},
   {goodProperty3: 'cde'},
   {goodProperty4: 'def'},
   {goodProperty5: 'fgh'}
];
```

However I'd like to filter out the bad properties before I get my new array. I'd like my array to only include these specific property names and filter everything else that I started with.

```
var possiblePropertyNames = ['goodProperty1', 'goodProperty2', 'goodProperty3', 'goodProperty4', 'goodProperty5'];
```

Comment: What's the actual problem/question? Iterate over `possiblePropertyNames` and use its elements to produce the expected output. `Array.prototype.map()` might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an implementation using `filter` and `map` on the object entries of response. In the filter stage I filter out only if it is available in `possiblePropertyNames`. Then in the map stage I return the array in the format you need

```js
var possiblePropertyNames = ['goodProperty1', 'goodProperty2', 'goodProperty3', 'goodProperty4', 'goodProperty5'];
var response = {badProperty1: "bad property text",goodProperty1: "abc",goodProperty2: "bcd",goodProperty3: "cde",goodProperty4: "def",goodProperty5: "efg",badProperty2: "fgh"}

var newFilteredStructuredArray = Object.entries(response).filter(([k,v]) => possiblePropertyNames.includes(k)).map(([k,v]) => ({[k]:v}))

console.log(newFilteredStructuredArray)
```

without es6

```js
var possiblePropertyNames = ['goodProperty1', 'goodProperty2', 'goodProperty3', 'goodProperty4', 'goodProperty5'];
var response = {badProperty1: "bad property text",goodProperty1: "abc",goodProperty2: "bcd",goodProperty3: "cde",goodProperty4: "def",goodProperty5: "efg",badProperty2: "fgh"}

var newFilteredStructuredArray = Object.keys(response)
.filter(function(a){
    return possiblePropertyNames.includes(a)
})
.map(function(b){
    return {[b]:response[b]}
})

console.log(newFilteredStructuredArray)
```

**UPDATE** better answer with just a `map` on the `possiblePropertyNames` array as pointed out by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) in the comments

```js
var possiblePropertyNames = ['goodProperty1', 'goodProperty2', 'goodProperty3', 'goodProperty4', 'goodProperty5'];
var response = {badProperty1: "bad property text",goodProperty1: "abc",goodProperty2: "bcd",goodProperty3: "cde",goodProperty4: "def",goodProperty5: "efg",badProperty2: "fgh"}

var newFilteredStructuredArray = possiblePropertyNames.map(prop => ({[prop]:response[prop]}))

console.log(newFilteredStructuredArray)
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer, but using a for...in loop.  Yet, I like your answer using Object.entries() much better.  +1

Comment: Awesome yes this exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not quite using ES6 could you convert this to not be ES6? Thanks

Comment: @user7814645 i removed destructuring, arrow fucntions. Object.entries() is not es6 but Im not sure. anyway Object.keys should work

Comment: @user7814645 tbh not sure of includes as well. need to check

Comment: Why `Object.entries()`/`.keys()` + `Array.prototype.filter()`? The "good" properties are all listed in `possiblePropertyNames`. Just iterate over that array: `possiblePropertyNames.reduce(...)`. One method vs. three (you don't need `.map()` with `.reduce()`)

Comment: @Andreas you are correct. Missed that completely. Just a map seems to be enough

Comment: @user7814645 I update the answer which can be done with a map only. better than what I had written earlier